# How to debug a js CLI application while running it from the command line?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I created a CLI application and I would like to debug it using the VSCode debugger in the real world. For example, if I wanted to debug create-react-app and step through the code as I'm running it on the command line, is that possible?

Comment: _"is that possible?"_  yes. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Comment: Okay, I don't see anything in there that shows if it's possible to run a command line tool and have it start the debugger, but thanks anyway.